# EF self referencing entity

Tags: entity-framework

Why is this EF 6 code generating an unexpected Code First Migration result? 
I would expect this code to generate only one ParentId that is a self referencing FK.
This is based on the article attached at the end which was based on EF 4.1. Did anything change in EF 6 that could affect the behaviour in this case?

Entity:

```
public class Category
{
  public int CategoryId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int? ParentId { get; set; }
  public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category> {
public CategoryMap() {
    HasKey(x => x.CategoryId);

    Property(x => x.CategoryId)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    Property(x => x.Name)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(255);

    HasOptional(x => x.Parent)
        .WithMany(x => x.Children)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
 }
}
```

Code First Migration **Result**:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Categories",
            c => new
                {
                    CategoryId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    ParentId = c.Int(),
                    Parent_CategoryId = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.CategoryId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Categories", t => t.Parent_CategoryId)
            .Index(t => t.Parent_CategoryId);
```

Code First Migration **Expectation**:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Categories",
            c => new
                {
                    CategoryId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    ParentId = c.Int()
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.CategoryId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Categories", t => t.ParentId )
            .Index(t => t.ParentId );
```

You can use this as a reference for further details: http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/using-self-referencing-tables

Comment: What is the error generated upon `Migration` attempt?

Comment: There is no error. I just don't understand why the result differs from what I expect.

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you use `HasMany().WithOptional().HasForeignKey()`?